# Adults department or adults' department?

Tags: possessives

Should it be *adults* department or *adults'* department?

> The Older Adults Department at CCSF offers non-credit classes specially designed for those 55 plus, but all are welcome to attend.

Source: [Older Adults](https://www.ccsf.edu/en/educational-programs/school-and-departments/school-of-health-and-physical-education/older_adults.html)

Comment: I edited your question so what you're actually asking is also in the body of the question rather than only in the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "Older Adults Department" without an apostrophe is fine. It is not really a possessive since it is just a place for "Older Adults"